# Algorithm for determining acceptable variance

Tags: algorithm, function, math

I have an application that is comparing numbers from two different reports. It is going to alert the user when the variance between the two numbers is over a certain threshold. I was originally going to use a 10% threshhold, but I realized that when Count A is ex. 10,000 a variance of 10% is too HIGH (meaning if there were 999 that would be excessive), but when Count A is only 10 a variance of 10% is too LOW (meaning that 2-3 / 10 would be an acceptable variance).

Just can't figure out how to do it, besides coding out

```
IF CountA <= 10 THEN AcceptableRate = 20%
If CountA > 10 THEN AcceptableRate = 15%
```

Does anybody know how to explain what I am trying to do here mathematically, and how it would be implemented?
I am sure this probably a simple question for somebody that is better at math than I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the formulas mentioned in previous answers, also consider using some power of n (where n is a reference number from one report or the other) as a tolerance.  Here is some python code and its results, illustrating several different powers of n:

```
j=10   
for i in range(6):
    print '{:8} {:8.1f} {:8.1f} {:8.1f} {:8.1f}'.format(j, j**0.33, j**.35, j**.37, j**.39)
    j *= 10

      10      2.1      2.2      2.3      2.5
     100      4.6      5.0      5.5      6.0
    1000      9.8     11.2     12.9     14.8
   10000     20.9     25.1     30.2     36.3
  100000     44.7     56.2     70.8     89.1
 1000000     95.5    125.9    166.0    218.8
```

Comment: I think this information will work for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you are trying to compare two different sets of data that should be similar, and you want to define a level of difference between the two data-sets which is some kind of acceptable level.

I suppose the approach that I would take would rely on a few factors, firstly, do you know the underlying distribution of the two datasets? For example if the data were normally distributed would it not be possible to find the probability of each datum existing in the other set?

On the other hand it might be possible to use [a Chi-square test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) to check the difference between the two datasets.

Another possibility is to use a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) to get a probability that one sample comes from the other.

Those would be my suggestions, however deciding on a cutoff value for this kind of thing is always subjective. A criterion that I used during my studies was [Chauvenet's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvenet%27s_criterion), this may also be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a criterion that is a more complex function of data set size than just proportion.  From the examples you give, I'm going to guess including a term based on the log of the data set size might be what you want.  Play around with expressions like

```
AcceptableN = 10 * log10(N) + 2
```

where `AcceptableN` is the acceptable number of outliers, N is the total data set size, and then `AcceptableRate = 100*AcceptableN / N`.

But there is no clear-cut direct mathematical formula to give you what you want, before getting a clearer idea of what you think the criteria should be for different N.

Answer (score 0):

I find standard deviation more intuitive than variance, because it's measured in the same units as the underlying uncertain quantity that you're dealing with.  Perhaps some percentage of the standard deviation would be an appropriate measure, because if you choose the right percentage it will push both your examples in the the right direction.